# Using OnClick and OnClientClick together doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I am using RadButton and RadWindow. On my RadButton I am trying to use OnClick and OnClientClick together to show a popup first and then go to a page via a server call.

```
 <div class="actionButtons">
                            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnMedLogin" CssClass="actionButton secondary" runat="server" Text="Doctor Login"
                                SingleClick="true" SingleClickText="Logging in" OnClick="btnDoctor_Click" OnClientClick="openwin();return false">
                            </telerik:RadButton>
                        </div>
```

When I just put

> OnClick="btnDoctor_Click"

It works fine. however I want my radwindow modal to show as well so I put

> OnClientClick="openwin();"

but it isn't working. I tried OnClientClicked but not working either.

Here is the rest of the code

```
   function openwin() {
            window.radopen(null, "RadWindow1");
        }

<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" Width="500px" Height="500px"> 
    <Windows> 
    <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" Modal="true" Behaviors="close" Title="Countdown Clock"> <ContentTemplate> 
    <div id="timerHorizontal">Some Text</div> 
    </ContentTemplate> </telerik:RadWindow> 
    </Windows>  </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

How can I make it so it goes to the page and my radwindow pop up shows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right name of the property is `OnClientClicked`, and it should be given a function name, so:

```
OnClientClicked="openwin"
```

This comes directly from [docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-server-side-properties-events.html):

> Sets a name of a JavaScript function that will be called when the RadButton is > clicked, after the OnClientClicking event.

Comment: It won't prevent the postback though.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev, there is little we can do about the API telerik provides. Probably function should return false to prevent postback.

Comment: correct, better return false and then maybe manually do the postback depending on the user action in the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer (to pass only the function name to the OnClientClicked property) is absolutely true, a subsequent postback will destroy your RadWindow. Thus, you will need to use AJAX for this RadButton so it does not dispose the RadWindow.